# Find the specific word in the text file and to store that word in array list

Tags: java

I want to find the specific word in the text file and store that word in the array of list.

I do not how it can be achieved or approached.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Would you please add some more information **and** the code you have written so far. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so please help me

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please before you will ask next time, read [mcve] and follow instructions described over there. 
Otherwise you can expect just closing your question, usually, we are there to help you, of course, but not for doing your homeworks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic solution:

```
public ArrayList getWords(String searchWord, String listOfWords){
    ArrayList<String> foundWords = new ArrayList<>();
    if (listOfWords.contains(searchWord)){
        foundWords.add(searchWord);
    }
return foundWords;
}
```